# Using JavaScript Fetch with Formidablejs, Expressjs

Tags: javascript, forms, http, fetch, formidable

I'm using Reactjs saga to send a post request using fetch. Also I'm trying to use formidable instead of usual body-parser. I'm getting weird parsing issues. What am I doing wrong?

```
// saga simplified piece of code
const { loginEmail, loginPwd } = request.payload;

let postLoginSubmitOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    loginEmail: loginEmail,
    loginPwd: loginPwd
  })
};

const response = yield call(fetch, `http://www.example.com/register`, postLoginSubmitOptions);

// expressjs side, simplified view

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('registering user');

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(`incoming fields via form parse`);
    console.log(fields); // { '{"loginEmail":"my-email@gmail.com","loginPwd":"my-password"}': '' }
    console.log(fields.loginEmail); // undefined
  });

  }
```

Comment: What are the "weird parsing issues"?

Comment: See console.log(fields) line.

Comment: Except for undefined, the others mean nothing. Explain what is wrong.

Comment: Explain how do you extract loginEmail and loginPassword from fields. Fields supposed to be an object like { fields: { loginEmail: "email@email.com" }} etc

Comment: Do you see that here fields is { "string" : "empty_string"}

Answer (score 0):

pass content type as json

```
let postLoginSubmitOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
  body: JSON.stringify({
    loginEmail: loginEmail,
    loginPwd: loginPwd
  })
};
```

Comment: With the first solution it gives me a parsing error because the form has already been parsed by formidable and I'm parsing it again with JSON.parse. With the second solution Error: bad content-type header, unknown content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(fields);`? the one in comments?

Comment: an empty object

Comment: If you think that in principle my code looks alright I'll keep trying. I just thought maybe there is something fundamentally wrong with it. Thanks man

Comment: do you get headers on server end? Try getting headers as set above

Comment: @dantenovski  Try editted code. if that does not work pass `mode: 'no-cors'` also in postLoginSubmitOptions.

Comment: Nope. I think it might be an issue with using fetch with formidable. I've asked this question at formidable github

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where exactly the problem was but tried encoding data differently and then it worked. Getting a nice parsed object now with formidable: `{ loginEmail: 'dan@dan.com', loginPwd: 'asjdfkjsadlf' }`

```
function sendData(data) {
  const { loginEmail, loginPwd } = request.payload;
  const body = { loginEmail, loginPwd };
  var urlEncodedData = "";
  var urlEncodedDataPairs = [];
  var name;

  for(name in body) {
    urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(body[name]));
  }
  urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');

  var httpHeaders = { 
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'Accept' : 'application/json'
  }

  let postOptions = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: new Headers(httpHeaders),
    /*mode: 'no-cors',*/
    body: urlEncodedData
  };

  try {
    const response = yield call(fetch, `http://www.example.com/register`, postOptions);
    const data = yield call([response, response.json]);
    console.log(`data returned by fetch`);
    console.log(data);
    yield put({type: 'LOGIN_SUBMIT_RESPONSE', payload: data.message})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`error fetch post object`);
  }
}
```

Thanks everyone!